# Read directory of avro files from HDFS into dataframe-like object in python

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, avro

Going to try and boil this question down to its essence: is there a convenient way in python 3 to read a directory of avro files -- not just a single file -- into a dataframe-like object?

This question relates to an application using Apache Livy and Spark that writes avro files to HDFS.  Using pyspark code, I am able to quickly count or transform avro files on HDFS.  However, I would like to read the contents of the avro files into memory as a dataframe-like object, that I could perform selects, sub-queries, and counts, as examples.  I understand this is possible from pyspark interactive shells, but this is operating with a Django app, so that's not an option.

I was hopeful a combination of the python [hdfs client library](http://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [fastavro](https://github.com/tebeka/fastavro) might be an option, but I'm encountering recursion depth errors, and that feels limited to file by file.

Stumbled on [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) as something that looks encouraging, with perhaps an [approach found here](https://gist.github.com/rmax/3eb3d098167e9ac9f3d7ce923569aad0).

In pseudo code, I would love something like the following, where obviously the syntax is made up:

```
df = some_library.load('/path/to/avro/files')
df.count()
OUT: 46323
df.sql.select("record WHERE record.url IS NOT NULL")
```

I understand that speed in which spark performs this kind of parsing and querying might not be possible, but I'm particularly interested in a python 3 approach for reading a *directory* of avro files.

As I type, I'm realizing that in-memory may not be scalable (looking at 50k, 100k, 500k records possible).  So perhaps it will always fall to sending python code to spark.  But, thought it couldn't hurt to ask.  Thanks.

**Update:** also [stumbled on this jar file](https://github.com/jwoschitz/avrocount) that counts avro files, and it works, but again, it's not quite what I'm looking for

**Update #2:** [cyavro](https://github.com/maxpoint/cyavro) is looking to be a viable option; very quick reading of 46k+ records, into a panda dataframe

Comment: What exactly is your question? it appears you are throwing technologies around. You have a spark tag but you ask nothing on spark. Please try to explain better what your are looking for.

Comment: Point taken.  In my defense, I do mention Spark in the question, and it's important for this question, which is why I included that tag.  I am aware of patterns with the interactive spark shell that I can do what I'm asking above, but I'm curious if there are non-spark alternatives for quickly reading avro files into a dataframe.  But, to your point, this question was more an exploration of available approaches/libraries with tangential relation to Spark, and not a question about Spark itself.  Cyavro appears to do just what I was hoping, and will submit an answer.

Comment: Then could you please explain better what it is you are trying to do? what is wrong with spark.read.avro?

Comment: The problem is, I want to read these avro files *outside* of a spark session or context.  Our Django app runs spark jobs in the background, but I would like a non-spark way of sorting and interacting with these avro files for other Django views.

Comment: then how is this related to spark?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **json** and **hdfscli** python packages.

To get started:

```py
from hdfs import InsecureClient


HDFS_HOSTNAME = 'master1.hadoop.com'
HDFSCLI_PORT = 50070
HDFSCLI_CONNECTION_STRING = f'http://{HDFS_HOSTNAME}:{HDFSCLI_PORT}'


hdfs_client = InsecureClient(HDFSCLI_CONNECTION_STRING)

avro_file = '/path/to/avro/file.avsc'

with hdfs_client.read(avro_file) as reader:
    content = json.load(reader)
```

Then you need to implement the loop (maybe with **hdfs_client.walk**) and transform to **pandas**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, [cyavro](https://github.com/maxpoint/cyavro) looks like an excellent solution to my question.  It provides a very quick reading of individual avro files, or a directory of avro files and concatenating them together, into a pandas dataframe.

While it appears to support some reading of other protocols like `http://` or `s3://`, it does not appear to natively support reading from `hdfs://` at this time.  But a viable alternative approach might be mounting the HDFS to the local filesystem, which would provide filesystem access that cyavro can act upon.

Comment: elements of your solution are in blaze/odo. please contribute to the avro backend if you can.

Comment: blaze/odo looks fascinating, thanks for sharing @MajidalDosari